# How to preserve structure across serialization with SimpleXML?

Tags: java, xml-parsing, xml-serialization, xml-deserialization, simple-framework

I'm new to SimpleXML, and I think it claims to be able to do this, so I must be doing something wrong.  Maybe you can help me out.

The problem is that if I have a parent object with two links to the same child object, when the parent is deserialized, I now have two links to identical, but different objects (different locations in memory).  This breaks the structure.

Here is what I'm doing:

**Topic.java:**

```
@Root (name = "Topic")
public class Topic {

    @Attribute (name = "name")
    String name = null;

    @Element (name = "id")
    int id = -1;

    @ElementList (name = "sparks")
    ArrayList<Spark> sparks = null;

    public Topic(
            @Attribute (name = "name") String inName,
            @Element (name = "id") int inID,
            @ElementList (name = "sparks") ArrayList<Spark> inSparks) {
        name = new String(inName);
        id = inID;
        if (inSparks == null) {
            sparks = new ArrayList<>(50);
        } else {
            sparks = inSparks;
        }
    }
[...]
```

**Spark.java**

```
@Root (name = "Spark")
public class Spark {

    @Element (name = "text", required = false)
    String text = null;

    @Element (name = "dateCompleted", required = false)
    Date dateCompleted = null;

    @Element (name = "rejected")
    boolean rejected = false;

    @Element (name = "delayedUntil", required = false)
    Date delayedUntil = null;

    @Attribute (name = "id")
    int id = -1; 

    @Element (name = "packName", required = false)
    String packName = null;

    public Spark(
            @Element (name = "text") String inText,
            @Attribute (name = "id") int inID,
            @Element (name = "packName") String inPackName) {
        text = new String(inText);
        id = inID;
        packName = new String(inPackName);
    }

    [...]
```

**Demonstration of the problem:**

```
    Serializer serializer = new Persister();
    File saveFile = new File(this.getFilesDir(), "test.xml");

    Topic testTopic = new Topic("TestTopic", 1);
    Spark newSpark = new Spark ("This is the sample text.", 1, "PretendPack");
    testTopic.sparks.add(newSpark);
    testTopic.sparks.add(newSpark);

    try {
        serializer.write(testTopic, saveFile);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Topic newTopic = null;
    try {
        newTopic = serializer.read(Topic.class, saveFile);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("IntimacyToolbox", "Was unable to deserialize from the savedData.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Spark spark1 = newTopic.sparks.get(0);
    Spark spark2 = newTopic.sparks.get(1);
    if (spark1 == spark2) {
        Log.d("IntimacyToolbox", "Good: sparks are the same.");
    } else {
        Log.d("IntimacyToolbox", "Bad: sparks are different objects.");
    }
```

After running this bit of code, the two sparks in the newTopic.sparks ArrayList are different objects.  Is there a way to have them deserialize as the same object?  I come from iOS, and the system there just magically works; seems like there should be something similar on Android; maybe SimpleXML isn't it, though.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is, use the CycleStrategy.